# how to send collection by compact to pdf function

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send an array per compact but when viewing it it throws an error.

**SaleController.php**

```
public function generarRecibo($id)
{
    $sales = Sale::with('client', 'products')->where('id', '=', $id)->get();

    $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.sales-recibo', compact(['sales']) );

    return $pdf->stream('Recibo N° '.$id.'.pdf');
}
```

[image]

**sales-recibo.blade.php**

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
    
    @foreach ($sales->products as $product)
        <tr>
            <td style="border: 0px;" colspan="3">{{ $product->name }}</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td style="border: 0px;">
                <ul>
                    <li>{{ $product->quantity }} X ${{ number_format($product->price, 0,',','.') }}</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
            <td style="border: 0px;" width="150px"></td>
            <td style="border: 0px;" width="150px">${{ number_format($product->price, 0,',','.') }}</td>
            
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `get()` use `find()` method

```
 $sales = Sale::with('client', 'products')->find($id);
```

and also you have issue with compact

```
 $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.sales-recibo', compact('sales') );
```